# Should I use mutableArray or mutableDictronary?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to fill a `muatableArray` or `mutableDictionary`. I will then take out 1 object, say 4, then I will need all elements beyond 4 moved by subtracting 1 from their index.

This is easy to do in a `mutableArray` with  `removeObjectAtIndex`. But the problem to that is, I will not be adding objects to every single index.

Here is the basic layout of what I mean:

```
 1. one
 2. two
 3. three
 // 4. (Empty)
 5. five
 6. six
 // 7. (Empty)
 // 8. (Empty)
 9. nine
 10. ten
```

So my question is, should I use a `mutableaArray`, and just add `nulls` to the empty indexs like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{
     if (![myArray objectAtIndex:i]) {
         [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
     }
}
```

Or should I use a `mutableDictionary`, and when I need to remove an object, I should just do it all manually like this:

```
[self.myDict removeObjectForKey:currentKey];
for (NSNumber *key in [[self.myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
  if ([key integerValue] > currentKey) {
    NSNumber *newKey = @([key integerValue]-1);
    self.myDict[newKey] = self.myDict[key];
    [self.myDict removeObjectForKey:key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{
     if (![myArray objectAtIndex:i]) {
         [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
     }
}
```

First, you are not turning on all the warnings that you should turn on. As evidence I take that you are using int i and not NSUInteger i. This is a very bad habit. Turning on warnings is a very cheap and effective method to find programming errors.

Second, don't use ! to check whether a pointer is nil. Do the decent thing and compare it to nil. You want to check that it is nil, so that is what you should write in your code. Writing the code in a way that it reflects what you want to do is a very cheap and effective method to avoid programming errors.

Third, this code is absolutely pointless. If i < myArray.count, then [myArray objectAtIndex:i] cannot possibly be nil. [myArray objectAtIndex:i] will never, ever, ever return nil.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections!! Really appreciate it!! So do you suggest I use the mutableArray instead of the mutableDictionary?